# Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs with list objects

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a worksheet function with list objects on it and it does not give the proper value.

The output is always 0.

```
Sub volsumif()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb2.Sheets("Dist_Summary")
    'Set a = wb2.Sheets("SALES").ListObjects("SALES").Range
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Dist_Perf Total Brands")
    Set ws3 = wb2.Sheets("SALES")
    'Set ws4 = wb2.Sheets("SALES_Target").ListObjects("SALES_TARGET").ListRows.Count
    Set ws5 = wb2.Sheets("Dump")
    Set ws6 = wb2.Sheets("Top_Accts")
    Set ws7 = wb2.Sheets("Per_Chn")

    //before ws3.range("Z:Z")

    ws2.Range("B83") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs _
        (ws3.ListObjects("SALES").DataBodyRange(0, 26), _
        ws3.ListObjects("SALES").DataBodyRange(0, 4), _
        ws2.Range("A82"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for editing can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to access the entire columns as arguments in `Sumifs`?
If so, try this:

```
ws2.Range("B83") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs _
    (ws3.ListObjects("SALES").ListColumns(26).DataBodyRange, _
    ws3.ListObjects("SALES").ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange, _
    ws2.Range("A82"))
```

Comment: only column z:Z which is 26 and column D:D which is four, i got an error type mismatch

Comment: @alkatraz Where does your table begin? Cell A1? Are you actually working on a Table Object? If your data begins in column A, then it should work. It works in my end.

Comment: I am accessing column D and Z

Comment: @alkatraz Yeah I know that. But your table should begin in A to use 26 and 4. If not you need to count what column Z and D in your table.